# jQuery slideToggle() on two items concurrently

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm in the process of creating a text slider, for headlines. I would like the currently displayed text to side out, at the same time that the new text is sliding in. Is there a way that I can use jQuerys `.slideToggle()` or `.slide()` concurrently to be able to do what I want?

Comment: there are lot of ways to do this , there are plugins available already. Otherwise you can use setTimout() and clearTimeOUt of javascript and do the same.

Comment: we have a done a image slider on www.allposters.com , see if you want the same stuff with text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the slideToggle function on both objects one after the other. The transition will happen concurrently.

```
$("#obj1").slideToggle();
$("#obj2").slideToggle();
```

Comment: I thought about this, as it seemed both the most simple and most logical, but I wasn't sure if obj2 would start the slide after obj1 would finish.

Comment: No, that would happen only if you use the callback procedure.

Comment: Isn't the jQuery shorthand `$`? (hint: yes)

Comment: @Eric: Thanks. Didn't notice the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new element for the new text, position it over the old element, then `slideToggle()` both of them.